# Performing basic calculations on Core Data attributes / columns

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am using Core Data based time series (entity/table) which consists of the following attributes / columns:

```
dateTime mc nd re
```

Based on the formula `result = (mc + nd) / re` I would like to calculate the result for each row and return the results (dateTime + value) in an array.

I tried the following code to perform the calculations on the database level but do get wrong results in my result array (multiple dateTime values per row, wrong calculation results). However, the `NSExpressionDescription` returns the correct formula when NSLogging it.

Do you have any idea on what might be wrong with my code?

```
NSString *divisorKeyPath = @"revenue"
NSExpression *marketCapExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"mc"];
NSExpression *netDebtExpression   = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"nd"];
NSExpression *divisorExpression   = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:
    divisorKeyPath];
NSExpression *evExpression        = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:
    @"add:to:"  
    arguments:@[marketCapExpression,netDebtExpression]];
NSExpression *divisionExpression  = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:
    @"divide:by:"
    arguments:@[evExpression, divisorExpression]];
NSString *divisionExpressionName = @"division";
NSExpressionDescription *divisionDescription  = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
divisionDescription.name                      = divisionExpressionName;
divisionDescription.expression                = divisionExpression;
divisionDescription.expressionResultType      = NSDoubleAttributeType;

NSFetchRequest *divisionRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:
   NSStringFromClass([SharePrice class])];
divisionRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"dateTime",divisionDescription];
divisionRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor 
   sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateTime" ascending:YES];
divisionRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

NSError *error;
NSArray *divisionResults = [self.managedDocument.managedObjectContext
   executeFetchRequest:divisionRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"results: %@",divisionResults);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Core Data. If you set the launch argument "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3" then you can see that the expression description is translated to the SQLite query

```
SELECT t0.ZDATETIME,  t0.ZMARKETCAP +  t0.ZNETDEBT /  t0.ZREVENUE FROM ZENTITY t0 ORDER BY t0.ZDATETIME
```

and not

```
SELECT t0.ZDATETIME,  (t0.ZMARKETCAP +  t0.ZNETDEBT) /  t0.ZREVENUE FROM ZENTITY t0 ORDER BY t0.ZDATETIME
```

as it should be.

The `divisionExpression` itself is correct. If you apply it to a single `sharePrice` object of your entity, using

```
NSNumber *x = [expression expressionValueWithObject:sharePrice context: nil];
```

it returns the expected result.